# React-Native: App stuck when debugging unless screen is clicked

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools, react-native

My Android App consists of two Screens: "Login" and "Dashboard".
The Login works just fine but the Dashboard is a troublemaker.

## **First Problem**:

On the Login Screen I can open the debug menu and everything works as expected. When I switch to the Dashboard screen I cannot open the menu anymore. If I enabled the Inspector in the Login screen and then go to the Dashboard screen, the Inspector disappears.

## **Second Problem**:

When I run the App without an attached debugger I get no Data in the Dashboard but the Login works as usual.

When I attach the debugger the App gets "stuck" a lot.
By clicking the screen (with attached debugger) when it is "stuck" the App sort of moves a step forward - When i click the screen often enough I end up with all the data I was expecting!
There are NO breakpoints set and I don't need to use the debugger at all, it just has to be attached.

The iOS counterpart seems to work just perfectly fine.

What could be wrong here?

## Update:

Im using React-Native 0.31.0

**Just to clarify**: My problem is not the debugger in itself. My problem is the fact, that I get no data without debugger but get all the data, when the debugger is attached (**on Android only!**).

Comment: which RN version are you using? >0.29 you could just try to run react-native log-android which gives you the same tool

Comment: also: can you show some code? hard to guess your solution

Comment: Well ... the project is fairly large already so I have no idea which part of the code I could show (cannot just copy paste all of it).

Comment: Am facing the same issue as well.. testing on Android.

Comment: @purezen pls see the answer I posted. Maybe it will help you, even though I found it hard to describe what the problem is/was because a bit of time has passed already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe to have figured out what the core of the problem was.

When debugging a React-Native App, the code is "run" by your Chrome which supports more of the javascript. (I find it hard to find the proper words for this...)

From the [React-Native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html) :

> On iOS simulators and devices, Android emulators and devices React
> Native uses JavaScriptCore which is the JavaScript engine that powers
> Safari. On iOS JSC doesn't use JIT due to the absence of writable
>
> executable memory in iOS apps.
> When using Chrome debugging, it runs all the JavaScript code within
> Chrome itself and communicates with native code via WebSocket. So you
> are using V8

In my case it were some functions that used `for of` loops or the `array.some` syntax.

I am not sure, what is currently supported by now so you (who ever comes across this problem) may want to update your react-native version.

Please see [this ECMAScript Compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)